# Chat in Ionic with Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to implement a chat page in my app.

In the constructor I ask for all the messages in the database:

```
this._DB
        .getDocument("chats", this.favour.chatId)
        .then(documentSnapshot => {
          var chat = documentSnapshot.data();
          for (var key in chat) {
            chat.key = chat[key];
          }
          delete chat.key;
          this.chat = chat;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

And the app load ok the messages with this html:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let messages of chat?.messages" class="chat" text-wrap [ngClass]="{'chat-partner' : messages?.askedName == localStorage?.name}">
            {{messages.message}}
        </ion-item>
```

To implemet a real time chat I see in the docs I have to use the onSnapshot method:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Then I use this function:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
this._DB._DB
  .collection("chats")
  .doc(this.favour.chatId)
  .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
    this.chat = doc.data();
    console.log(this.chat);
  });
this.content.scrollToBottom();
```

}

But the problem is that this.chat is showed ok in the console by the console.log, but the html dont refresh it :-(

I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

PS: I see maybe is confuse in the onSnapshot function I use this._DB._DB, this is because in the provider (the _DB) I don't have that functión and I make it public to can use in other place and can do tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find a solution.

Looks like the problem is the object this... is diferent in the component like in the function called by onSnapshot.

I solved creating a different function:

```
  observingChat(objectThis){
    if(objectThis.favour.chatId){
    this._DB._DB
      .collection("chats")
      .doc(objectThis.favour.chatId)
      .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
        objectThis.chat = doc.data();
        objectThis.content.scrollToBottom();
      });    
    } 
  }
```

That recibe the object this, and call it from the ionViewDidEnter()

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.content.scrollToBottom();
    this.observingChat(this);
  }
```

I don't know why or where the object this change.... if anybody can clarify and say me if the solution is correct I will be vefry gratefull :-)